# How to put my PHP Imagick extension running in Windows in my Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, imagick

I'm here with a problem.
I have an web app which is running in Laravel and, in a route, is displaying the first page of the PDF file. I used a PHP package to do that assignment and I'm using that package in the following code:

```
public function returnPDF($id) {
    $evento = evento::find($id);
    $upload = upload::find($evento->upload_id);
    $a_filename = $upload->filename;

    $path = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . $a_filename;
    $imagepath = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . "seekanddestroy". $id . ".jpg";
    $pdf = new Pdf($path);
    $pdf->setPage(1)->saveImage($imagepath);


    if (!File::exists($imagepath)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($imagepath);
    $type = File::mimeType($imagepath);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

The package that I've used is this code it's on the following link:
https://packagist.org/packages/bnbwebexpertise/pdf-to-image.

For this package, I've installed the Imagick and Ghostscript, softwares which the package requires to run the code above, in my Windows PC and installed the PHP Imagick extension in my XAMPP, following a set of instructions which were gaven to me.
The installation were successful, as [you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xWf.png), but it doesn't show the image, as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B77n.png).

Here, I share the HTTP headers requested on the comments.
[image]

Once again, I share the output of the error from that route.

[image]

The error above comes from the following line of code:

```
$pdf->setPage(1)->saveImage($imagepath);
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Can you try doing ```return response()->file($imagepath)```

Comment: Also, to find the root cause, can we see the response headers from your network tab when you visit the route.

Comment: Hi, Kurt Friars. The code above gives me the same error..

Comment: "The error above comes from the following line of code:" What is the error? Not google chrome's ```err_connection_reset```, the actual error from PHP.

Comment: Hi, Kurt Friars. What I'm trying to say is the following: the error is from PHP, which occurs on that line of code. When I run the Laravel app on that route, it crashes on that line of code and I don't know why. I can't identify the error, that's it.

Comment: Check your logs etc.. we can't help you without an error.

Comment: Are you just trying to convert the first page of a pdf to an image? Because there are other ways to do that with Imagick you can try, if you can't find the error.

Comment: How can I check my logs?

Comment: Hi, Kurt Friars, I followed one of your advices and I executed the following code: `exec("magick convert " .  $path . " " . $imagepath);`. It executed successfully.